# Change javascript script tags before download

Tags: javascript

During development, I'd like to modify the urls of my javascript files to append an epoch/nonce to the `src` querystring, so that on each refresh it downloads the file again.

Is this possible? I've tried the following code to modify the script tags (which are in the `HEAD`), but they download before the code fires.

```
var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = (r.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    r[i].setAttribute("src", r[i].getAttribute('src') + "?v=" + (new Date()).getTime());
}
```

The script tags are dynamically rendered by .NET MVC Optimizations, so I can't use `document.write` to insert them in the DOM - I have to start from the point where they are already in the DOM. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You should do this on the serverside, in exactly the code that dynamically renders these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you put the attempt above all other scripts, then those script elements have not been parsed and added to the DOM yet, so you won't see them returned by `document.getElementsByTagName`.

If you put the attempt after the other scripts, then it's too late as they've already been loaded.

You would be better off using cache-control headers to instruct the browser not to cache these files.